# I can't find out how to make my slideshow transition in the way I made it

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I made a slideshow using HTML, CSS and Javascript. 
The things is, the way I made it, I can't figure out how to actually make it *slide,* with a transition. 
I made it so that the picture are defined as a style background, not just an image. Now I need to know how I can transition between the containers...

Unfortunately I can't just use bootstrap, but I'm trying to make something like the carousel here: http://www.rpgmakerweb.com/

What I have now.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("carouselbackground");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.carouselholder {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.carouselbackground {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
.carouselcontent {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1024px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  float: center;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="carouselholder">
  <div class="carouselbackground" style="background-image: url('pics/nightview.jpg');">
    <div class="carouselcontent">
      Text here
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="carouselbackground" style="background-image: url('pics/Lake-pond.jpg');">
    <div class="carouselcontent">
      Text 2
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="carouselbackground" style="background-image: url('pics/animeik.jpg');">
    <div class="carouselcontent">
      Text 3.
    </div>
  </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)"> &#10094; </a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)"> &#10095; </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Why set a background image instead of using `<img>`? P.S. `center` is not a valid value for `float`.

Comment: I have it set as a background and I have things in front of it. If I use image it goes on top of the rest... Thanks for the float thing!

Comment: It's not necessary to do it that way and many image sliders implement something [similar to this](https://jsfiddle.net/ze5ux13x/).

Comment: I tried that, but when I use position absolute with top left and right, my overlay is not responsive anymore. I want my overlay to be centered at all costs...

Comment: I altered it so it should work with more pictures, but it doesn't. Leaving that aside, would you maybe know how I can transition between the div's I made using JS? It's the same class, but they are used multiple times and I want them to transition to the next one...